# Pandas read json format data

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas

I have a json column in one dataframe.

The whole dataframe looks like

[image]

The "customDimensions" column is the json column and the data is like

```
[{'index': '4', 'value': 'North America'}]
```

I want to flatten the column to the following 2 columns
customDimensions.index, customDimensions.value

How do i do this?

Comment: Is possible add data sample in format `json`?

Comment: If you're creating a dataframe out of a nested JSON, use json_normalize

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with `ast.literal_eval` for convert to list of dict, [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is for extract column and last[`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
#if values are strings
print (type(df.loc[0,'customDimension']))
<class 'str'>

import ast

df1 = (pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x)[0] for x in df.pop('customDimension')])
         .add_prefix('customDimensions.'))
```

---

```
#if values are lists
print (type(df.loc[0,'customDimension']))
<class 'list'>


df = pd.DataFrame([x[0] for x in df.pop('customDimension')]).add_prefix('customDimensions.')

df = df.join(df1)
```

If source is `json`, better is use [`json.json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html).

```
#not tested, depends of json format and data
df = json_normalize(j, 'customDimension', ['channelGrouping','date'])
```

Comment: You could also use apply.
`def getCol(x,col):
       return x[col]
df["customDimensions.index"] = df["customDimensions"].apply(lambda x:getCol(x,"index"))`

Comment: You are awesome! My data is <class 'str'>, and your answer solved my problem perfectly!